# Going to a custom step with jQuery-steps

Tags: jquery, forms, wizard, jquery-steps

I am using a [jQuery-steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/GettingStarted) on my app to for a wizard-like situation. I am having trouble finding out how to change to a custom step though. Any help with this one?

```
$(function () {
    $("#wizard").steps({
        headerTag: "h2",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        enableFinishButton: false,
        labels: {
            next: $('#next').html(),
            previous : $('#previous').html()

        },
        onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex)
        {
            if( priorIndex == 0) {
                var selected = $('input[name=radio_wizard]:checked', '#radio_wizard').val()
                switch( selected ){
                    case 1:
                        // GOTO 1 
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // GOTO 2 
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        // GOTO 3 
                        break;
                }
            }
      }
}
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 33):

I did this so I created this new function:

```
function _goToStep(wizard, options, state, index)
{
    return paginationClick(wizard, options, state, index);
}
```

And the call that is not implemented, put this:

```
$.fn.steps.setStep = function (step)
{

    var options = getOptions(this),
        state = getState(this);

    return _goToStep(this, options, state, step);

};
```

Just taking advantage of what already existed plugin.

Use:

```
wizard.steps("setStep", 1);
```

Comment: Why don't you submit this as a pull request?

Comment: For all I want to mention to be careful to change the signature from `function(index,step)` to the `function(step)` above mentioned by @Fernando Tholl

Comment: I added this to my steps plugin file, but still complaining and says not yet implemented! Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Same for me : Inside $.fn.steps.setStep, it says that 'getOptions' is not implemented. I have a hard time picture what is the "this" and the scope of setStep's body, and to which object getOptions is supposed to belong.

Answer (score 21):

I found a simple way to do this.
you can use the jquery function

```
$("#wizard-t-2").get(0).click();
```

assuming you know what step you want to go to.
this example would bring you to the third step of the wizard.
use chromes editor to figure out what the exact id is of the step you want to go to.

Answer (score 20):

```js
stepsWizard = $("#wizard").steps({
        forceMoveForward : true,
        enablePagination: false,
        titleTemplate : '<span class="number">#index#.</span> #title#'
    });

stepsWizard.steps("next"); // this will send us on next step :-)
```

Comment: Yes, but the question was about going to a custom step, not the next step.

Comment: This answer may be irrelevant to this question but this helped me for other type of requirement. Please don't remove it.

Answer (score 19):

You can create a custom implementation with a simple loop:

```
$.fn.steps.setStep = function (step)
{
  var self = $(this);
  var currentIndex = self.steps('getCurrentIndex');
  // Calculates the number of missing steps to get to the desired step
  var missingSteps = Math.abs(step - currentIndex);
  // The method then determines whether to navigate forward or backward to the desired step by checking if the step parameter is greater than the current index
  var direction = step > currentIndex ? 'next' : 'previous';
  // Move forward or backward by one step each time the loop runs, until it reaches the desired step
  for(var i = 0; i < missingSteps; i++){
    self.steps(direction);
  } 
};
```

And you can execute this new method in the below way:

```
$("#form").steps("setStep", 4); //based on 0 (set the index)
```

Comment: This one seems less elegant than the top answer, but unlike the top answer (which has that "getOptions" issue) it works for me -- using Steps 1.1.0.

Comment: tried above all, but didn't work for me. this one worked.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/blob/master/build/jquery.steps.js), it seems to lack that functionality as of right now:

```js
/*  
 * Sets a specific step object by index.  
 *  
 * @method setStep  
 * @param index {Integer} An integer that belongs to the position of a step  
 * @param step {Object} The step object to change  
 *
 */
$.fn.steps.setStep = function (index, step) 
{
    throw new Error("Not yet implemented!"); 
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Basing on @AbdulJamal answer, I've implemented it for any step:

```
$(function () {
    var stepsWizard = $("#wizard").steps({
        ...
    });

    // step variable handles current step (from 0)
    for(var i=0; i<step; i++) {
        stepsWizard.steps("next");
    }
});
```

Note that `step` variable must be defined and equal or greater than 0.

Comment: This will trigger the stepping events every step of the way. A way to go directly to the desired step seem like a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

I did something like below to get it worked:

```
stepsWizard = $("#wizard").steps({
    headerTag: "h2",
    bodyTag: "section"
});

var indx = 3;
for (i = 0; i <= indx; i++) {
 stepsWizard.steps("next");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Created this new function:

```
function _goToStep(wizard, options, state, index)
{
    return paginationClick(wizard, options, state, index);
}
And the call that is not implemented, put this:
```

Call that is not implemented, put this:

```
$.fn.steps.setStep = function (step)
{

    var options = getOptions(this),
        state = getState(this);

    return _goToStep(this, options, state, index); //Index Instead step

};

wizard.steps("setStep", 1);
```

**works just fine**

Answer (score 2):

[image]

take the id of the step you want go and add a trigger!

```
$("#steps-uid-0-t-1").trigger("click");
```

Comment: I highly recommend your solution. Simple and Robust

Answer (score 1):

```
function GotoSpecificStep(action, currentStep, number) {
    try
    {
        var stepsTogo = parseInt(currentStep) - parseInt(number);
        for (i = 1; i <= Math.abs(parseInt(stepsTogo)) ; i++) {
            if (action == "next") {
                $(".btnNext").click();
            }
            else if (action == "prev") {
                $(".btnPrevious").click();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(exception)
    {
        MsgBox(exception.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20683212/3079302) by @FernandoTholl, for clarification, `wizard.steps("setStep", 1);` goes in `onStepChanged`

```
$('#wizard').steps({
  onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
      //blah, blah, blah, some code here
  },
  onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
    $('#wizard').steps("setStep", 3);
  },
  onFinished: function () {
      ///more code
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution:

```
var desiredStep = 0;
$("#steps-uid-0-t-" + desiredStep).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onInit: function(event) {
        let div = event.currentTarget;
        let lis = div.getElementsByTagName('li');
        // Choose second tab
        // active is just show style, only effective after clicking tag a.
        lis[1].className += ' active';
        $(lis[1]).children('a').click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this so I created this new function in jquery.steps.js, is important inserts before the `$.fn.steps.setStep` function:

```
function _goToStep(wizard, options, state, index)
{
    return paginationClick(wizard, options, state, index);
}
```

In jquery.steps.js find the `$.fn.steps.setStep = function` and replace then with:

```
$.fn.steps.setStep = function (step)
{

    var options = getOptions(this),
        state = getState(this);

    return _goToStep(this, options, state, step);

};
```

Use:

`wizard.steps("setStep", 1);`

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution i found.

1. Find your tablist item id (in my case it is '#ef_users_list-t-')
2. Trigger click event

```
var tablist_item = 'ef_users_list-t-';

var step = 2; // step number to jump to
$(tablist_item+step).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery('#multisteps_form').steps(
{
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    autoFocus: true,
   // startIndex:2,

    onStepChanging: function() 
    {
        var myform=jQuery('#multisteps_form').serializeArray();
        
        jQuery.ajax({
                url: ajx_url,
                type: 'post',
                data: 
                {
                    'action':'final_submit_data',
                    myform:myform,
                },
                success: function (form_res) 
                {
                    jQuery('#form_submit').html(form_res);
                }
            });
        
        return true; // Most Important
    },
    onFinishing: function() 
    {
        
    },
    onFinished: function() 
    {
    
    }
});
```

Comment: This is Perfectlly working in My System ... Just check sure u will get idea of it.... U need to add CDN Link or custom CDN link  For it ..