# Jquery-steps : Preserve last selected tab after postback

Tags: jquery-steps

I am using Jquery-Steps to produce a Tabs effect on one of my aspx pages. Each tab has a Save button, which calls a server method to save values to db. However, on page reload, it by default selects the first tab. I am calling dvProfile.steps() method. This is how my tags are :

```
<div id="dvProfile">
<h1>Tab1</h1>
<div id="tab1">

</div>
<div id="tab2">
</div>

..... so on

</div>
```

I want to programmatically select the last selected tab. Thanks for the help in advance!

Sri

Comment: It would be easier to help you to solve your problem when you add some of the script to your example - how you call the method - and is it really necessary to reload the page? If, it would be possible to solve it using something like a callback-function or  - maybe - a cookie.

Comment: This thread here solved my issue. Thanks for the help.

[StackOverflow Question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957432/going-to-a-custom-step-with-jquery-steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, Theres is property called 'saveState' , which when set to true saves the state(last selected tab) to a cookie.